# Executing Default Finish action from .net assembly

Tags: web8.5, templating, tbb, .net

I want to execute default finish action compound tbb from .NET code. Is it possible and how? Or any other TBB that comes with Tridion installation?

Comment: Default Finish action should be part of the Default Templates , you can use this on Component Template and Page Template , You can execute this from the .net code may be by referring to the wedav url on your .net code. Not sure why you want to execute the TBB from the .net code

Comment: I know i can use them and that is the way we did it by now. What I want to achieve is executing it from the .net assembly, or to be more precise, the classes they use.

Comment: May be it’s possible if you have the default template solution where you call from your .net assembly.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is the ability to automatically expose assemblies to C# script fragments [per the documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/467495/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/exposing-custom-apis-in-your-c--script-fragment-template-building-block).

The next best thing is replicating the logic yourself. Which classes were you interesting in using? The community might have some utilities, examples, or tips on how to get the same results.

Comment: It's been a long time, but I've done this in the XView implementation to allow templating inside .NET with a single TBB. Check de Decorate method in this class: https://github.com/hoangchu/xview-codesamples/blob/master/Source/Templating/DecorationFilters/DefaultFinishActionsDecorationFilter.cs. Here is the source of the Context class which defines the methods RenderExtractBinariesFromHtml and RenderITemplate: https://github.com/hoangchu/xview/blob/master/Source/XView/TridionContext.cs